# Adaptive Chained Payments IPN not updating

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm testing a chained payments implementation in the PayPal sandbox and it works fine for normal transactions with a primary receiver and up to 2 secondary receivers. I'm logging all the IPN responses in my database.

If a payment is updated, for example I refund the payment, another IPN is sent with the updated information. This is the expected behaviour.

However, when testing with 'foreign' accounts I noticed that I get the following:

```
transaction[1].pending_reason : MULTI_CURRENCY
transaction[1].status : Pending
...
transaction[2].pending_reason : MULTI_CURRENCY
transaction[2].status : Pending
```

The reason being that these accounts are set up in EUR and the payment currency was USD.

So I log in to both accounts and accept the payments. However an updated IPN is never sent out so they remain as pending in my records.

Should I be expecting another IPN or does this just not happen when a pending payment is accepted by the receiver? The application will be used by PayPal account holders in various country/currency combinations so it would be useful to know what the expected behaviour is.

Comment: did you solve this problem? any updates?

Comment: Sadly not, and unfortunately I think adaptive payments is somewhat abandoned by PayPal as they move towards REST APIs (wish they'd hurry up!). We haven't actually hit this problem in the wild yet, we just have to make sure each receiver is correctly set up to receive payments in the three currencies we use (GBP, USD and SGD). Worst case I think we'd manually have to approve payments on our system that didn't clear with PayPal until the second attempt but this would only happen once or twice per recipient depending on how their account was set up.